# prove series converges for all $p>1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Problem: If $a_k \geq 0$ is a bounded sequence, prove that $$\sum_{ k=1} ^ {\infty} \frac{a_k}{(k+1)^{p}}$$ converges for all $p>1$.

**proof:** Suppose $a_k \geq 0$ is a bounded sequence, then since $0 \leq a_k \leq b_k$ we have $ 0 \leq \frac{1}{(k+1)^k} \leq \frac{1}{k^p}$ for all $p$.

Then, we know $\Sigma k_1 ^\infty\frac{1}{k^p}$ converges for all $p>1$. And $a_k$ is bounded sequence so it's convergent and $\Sigma k_1 ^ \infty \frac{a_k}{k^{p}}$ is convergent when $p>1$.

Thus by the comparison test $\Sigma k_1 ^ \infty \frac{a_k}{(k+1)^{p}}$ converges for all $p>1$.

Can anyone please verify the proof? Any suggestion would help.
Thank you.

Comment: Basically right approach, but  a few changes are needed. Since the sequence $(a_k)$ is bounded, there is a $b$ such that $a_k\le b$ for all $b$. We have $\frac{a_k}{(1+k)^p}\le \frac{b}{(1+k)^p}\le \frac{b}{k^p}$. Then Comparison. Of course the sequence $(a_k)$ need not converge, but that is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why is $\{a_{k}\}$ convergent, when $a_{k}$ is bounded?? Consider $a_n=\{1,2,1,2,1,2....\}$. It is bounded but not convergent.

You can compare with the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p}}$ and the fact that $a_n$ is bounded.